# SimpleHTTPServer only works with localhost - "::" instead of <ip address>

Tags: python, windows, simplehttpserver

I try opening a SimpleHTTPServer in windows and I can only access it with localhost:.

This is what I get:

python -m http.server 80
Serving HTTP on :: port 80 (http://[::]:80/) ...

Notice that my ip address is "blank". I don't use a VPN or anything like that.

When I try it in Linux in my VM, it works as it should (using ip address + port instead of localhost +  port), though I can only access the server from inside the VM (which is understandable).

Thanks is advance

Comment: Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 80 (http://0.0.0.0:80/) is what i get when i run the same command. 0.0.0.0 means its in broadcast mode which means any system in the network can access it.

Comment: Have you tried using `--bind` option with your IP?

Comment: Okay, thanks, it works with --bind. Do you happen to know why it refuses to pick my ip address automatically, though?